# Laravel axios file download

Tags: laravel, http, download, vuejs3, response-headers

I'm using laravel8 and vue3 Quasar framework.
When I download image file, download.txt file was downloaded.

So I checked header file, It's good looks like below

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
Cache-Control: public
Content-Description: File Transfer
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=KakaoTalk_20190904_163948074.jpg
Content-Length: 3532575
Content-Type: application/pdf
Date: Sun, 30 Jan 2022 03:33:17 GMT
Date: Sun, 30 Jan 2022 03:33:17 GMT
Host: localhost
Last-Modified: Sat, 29 Jan 2022 13:52:42 GMT
Vary: Origin
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.1.0
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 52
```

but I tried to check console.log(response.header.filename), it returned undefined.

Below code is download method

```
  public function download($id)
  {
    $file = File::findOrFail($id);
    
    $filepath = Storage::disk('files')->path($file->name);
    $filename = $file->origin_name.'.'.$file->extension;

    $headers = [
      'Content-Type' => $file->mime_type,
      'Content-Encoding' => 'UTF-8',
      'Content-Description' => 'File Transfer',
      'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment;filename='.$filename,
    ];

    return \Response::download($filepath, $filename, $headers);
  }
```

Below is cors.php in Laravel

```
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'login', 'logout'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

Below is download method in Vue

```
    const downloadFile = (fileId) => {
      api({
        method: 'get',
        url: `files/${fileId}/${props.model}/${props.modelId}/download`,
        responseType: 'arraybuffer'
      })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.headers.filename)
          const blob = new Blob([response.data])
          saveAs(blob, response.headers.filename)
        })
    }
```

And when I input parameter 'good.jpg' instead of response.headers.filename, it works file is download as name of good.jpg

I guess axios can't get headers information properly.

Thank so much read this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access file name like this. There are couple of ways that you can find by searching but here is a simple one:

```
filename = response.headers['Content-Disposition'].split("filename=")[1]
```

Comment: Thank you your help. But I can only access headers via dot notation.